# Python: compile with optimize and execute

Tags: python, optimization, compilation

my Python program is slow and I wanted to test if it would speed up if I complied it (with code optimization) and executed it afterward.

So what are the terminal commands to do so? I'm searching for something like

```
pythoncompile -optimize my_code.py my_compiled_code.out
pythonexecute my_compiled_code.out
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python source code is automatically compiled into Python byte code by the CPython interpreter. Compiled code is usually stored in PYC (or PYO) files, and is regenerated when the source is updated, or when otherwise necessary.

Generally speaking; you can speed up execution with better hardware, or with code optimization by rewriting your code.

For example you can use [the python profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to look for weak spots in execution time.